# SQUASHFS errors when the server is running

Tags: linux, squashfs

I am getting SQUASHFS errors when the server is running:

```
[Mon Nov 13 08:15:56 2023] SQUASHFS error: zlib_inflate error, data probably corrupt
[Mon Nov 13 08:15:56 2023] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x53c92958
[Mon Nov 13 08:15:56 2023] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data cache entry [53c92958]
[Mon Nov 13 08:15:56 2023] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 53c92958, size a72b
```

The linux OS is `CentOS Linux 7 (Core)`